# Copy folder and content to different folder on Windows 10

Tags: windows, directory, copy

I am in the folder `Temp` it has two subfolders `Test_1` and `Test_2` with some files in them I would like to copy whole folder `Test_1` into `Test_2`, so that I would have `Temp\Test_2\Test_1`. I tried on Windows

```
copy Test_1 Test_2
```

But it only copies the content of the folder not the folder itself. I tried adding `\` everywhere, but it did not help.

Comment: If memory serves, the Windows commany you want is `xcopy`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy

Comment: @bitfiddler, I tried: `xcopy Test_1 Test_2`, but still it copies only files inside folder.

Comment: Take a look at the doc I linked for the switches to control directory inclusion.